# Rewriting ArrayList XML serialisation with jackson-dataformat-xml

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

If I use jackson-dataformat-xml to serialise an ArrayList of JsonNode it produces the following:

```
<ArrayList><item>...</item><item>...</item></ArrayList>
```

I'd like to have it read:

```
<events><event>...</event><event>...</event></events>
```

I've tried using a custom serialiser and does give me the `<event/>` tags I want but it also still wraps everything in an `<ArrayList><item></item></ArrayList>`

```
public class ArrayListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ArrayList<JsonNode>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(ArrayList<JsonNode> value, JsonGenerator gen,
            SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeStartObject();

        for (JsonNode node : value) {
            gen.writeObjectField("event", node);
        }

        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<ArrayList<JsonNode>> handledType() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<ArrayList<JsonNode>> typeClass = (Class<ArrayList<JsonNode>>)(Class<?>)List.class;
        return typeClass;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try #writeObjectFieldStart("events") method.

Comment: Yeah, I get an error saying java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider defining the XML element names using [annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#additional-annotations). Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonXmlArray {
    static class Document {
        @JsonProperty
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "events")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "event")
        List<String> events = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new Document()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<Document xmlns=""><events><event>a</event><event>b</event></events></Document>
```

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to do this without Annotations.. anyone know if there is?